# How can I launch a python script on windows?

Tags: python

I have run a few using batch jobs, but, I am wondering what would be the most appropriate? Maybe using time.strftime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to do recurring scheduled tasks, then the Task Scheduler (Vista) or Scheduled Tasks (XP and, I think, earlier) is the appropriate method on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I'd second using the Task Scheduler.

I have also read about a 'cron-like' python based application PyCron - http://www.bigbluehost.com/article4.html . If you're from the Unix end of town you might find it more familiar than the Windows scheduler. Never used it myself but it might be of interest.